# Connection pooling through an F5 Big-Ip SQL VIP

Tags: f5-big-ip

I've got a Big-IP pool managing a couple SQL servers in an active/inactive rollover approach - there's only ever one in the pool at a time.

Initially I was enabling/disabling the nodes in the pool, but I found that due to connection pooling, active connections did not cut over.

Instead, I've used their MSSQL monitor to flag which server is active/inactive, so the nodes are actually taken "Down" instead of just "Disabled". Things work better, except that the very first query after a rollover errors out, as the connection is dropped. I've played with the Pool's "Action On Service Down" settings, but none of the options (None/Drop/Reject/Reselect) seems to solve the problem - first call for each active pool after the switch always returns a connection error.

Short of turning off connection pooling, any ideas for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Priority Group Activation on your node pool. Set the Priority Group Activation to be "Less than..." 1 available members. Then assign the node you want to be active with a Priority Group of "2". If you don't want it to switch over back to the primary node when it comes back after an outage, be sure to set "Manual Resume" to "Yes" on your health monitor.